# Why would reinstallation of ansible cause 'Attempted to read "/etc/ansible/hosts" as YAML' error

Tags: ansible

#### The salient point here is that all worked until a re-installation of the same version of ansible. (post note: re-installation turned out to be irrelevant)

```
# rpm -qa |grep ansible
ansible-2.3.1.0-1.el7.noarch

# ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
   configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
   python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jul  3 2018, 06:28:28) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28.0.1)]
```

The following started happening yesterday evening after I removed and reinstalled ansible while testing; everything worked well until this point.  The ansible version is unchanged!  The format of the hosts file, yml files and execution command is also unchanged.  Anyone have an idea as to what might be causing it?

`# ansible-playbook do-all.yml`

```
ERROR! Attempted to read "/etc/ansible/hosts" as YAML: Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/hosts': line 47, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:

    [baremetal]
    host-01
    ^ here

Attempted to read "/etc/ansible/hosts" as ini file: /etc/ansible/hosts:69: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: stage-operator
```

`# cat /etc/ansible/hosts`

```yaml
......
## [dbservers]
##
## db01.intranet.mydomain.net
## db02.intranet.mydomain.net
## 10.25.1.56
## 10.25.1.57
# Here's another example of host ranges, this time there are no
# leading 0s:
## db-[99:101]-node.example.com
[baremetal]
host01
host02

# cat do-all.yml
---
 - include: baremetal/create-user.yml
......

# cat baremetal/create-user.yml
---
- hosts: baremetal
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Create dev group
    group:
      name: dev
      state: present
......
```

Comment: Please provide context around line 69 of your hosts file. I guess you've commented out some lines but not it's group, so ansible is confused about file format.

Comment: Good man Konstantin!  I totally missed the '69' ref and didn't see the double entry in the file.

stage-operator  ansible_host=10.10.10.5   stage-operator ansible_gateway=10.10.10.1

Comment: Must check see how this double entry appeared.  Thanks again.  You should throw in as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> Please provide context around line 69 of your hosts file.
>
> I guess you've commented out some lines but not it's group, so ansible
> is confused about file format.

Comment: Found cause of the double entry, 'cut' not applied in the following.  Very odd as it was before yesterday evening.

crudini --set /etc/ansible/hosts $group $host "ansible_host=$(grep $host /etc/hosts | cut -f1) ansible_gateway=$staging_gate
way"

On to this investigation now. :)

Comment: For completeness, here is that cause. staging & production entries in /etc/ansible/hosts are derived from /etc/hosts.  The cut failed due to spaces instead of tab between IP and hostname; cut doesn't treat them the same.  Changed '/etc/hosts | cut -f1' to 'tr -s ' ' /etc/hosts | cut -d ' ' -f1' to cover all situations.

Comment: Probably better using | awk '{print $1}'